# Get the discount % in shopping cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get the discount % of the total items in the cart. I couldnt find any core method to do so, so this is what i tried :

```
$total = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
if(!empty($total['subtotal']) && !empty($total['discount']))
{
    $subtotal = $total['subtotal']->getValue(); 
    $discount = $total['discount']->getValue();
    $discPer  = -(($discount/$subtotal) * 100);
    $discountPer = round($discPer,2);
    echo $discountPer;
}
```

This works fine. but now i have customized discounts. for an eg. discount is not applied when a specific custom option is selected. So for those products i want to display the discount % like original, even when discount is not applied. Thanks.

Comment: I want it in `checkout/total/default.phtml`

Comment: You can set it in **Shopping Cart Price Rule**.